# Copy string without strcpy

Tags: c, string, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str, *temp;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    temp = str;
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this valid code to copy one string to another without using `strcpy()` function?

Comment: It is not copying the string. It is assigning pointers, which is not invalid by itself, but has specific use-cases.

Comment: You can check by yourself with something like `str[0] = '*';` and then `printf("%s", temp);` and see that you modified `temp` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are merely copying the starting address of `str` to `temp`. This means that any changes to `temp` will be reflected in `str` as well, since they point to the same memory. It does not truly emulate `strcpy(dest, src)`, which creates a *separate copy* of the null-terminated string pointed to by `src` starting at the memory location pointed to by `dest`.

So, to answer your question as asked: no.

If your intent is to avoid the O(n) running time of `strcpy`, that's also something you can't really do.

If you're required by a programming assignment or exercise to create code functionally equivalent to `strcpy`, here is a high-level description of the algorithm it uses:

1. Copy the character in `*source` to `*destination`
2. If the character that was just copied was the null terminator, exit.
3. Otherwise, increment the pointer to `source`, and increment the pointer to `destination`.
4. Go to step 1.